# Core Data, only one object, one entity, some attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have been working with Core Data in another App that has a tableView where the user can add objects, the usual stuff for what you can find tutorials everywhere.

Now for another App, I just want one single object that has one entity and some attributes. All this should be much easier than dealing with adding objects and so on, but I have no clue on how to achieve this. I am not that experienced and normally I follow tutorials and edit them to my needs, but I can t find any examples for this.

How would I set this up? Would I add one object only once at first App start in App delegate and then never again? Would this be the right way?

And then just edit the attributes for that object while using the app?

I don t want to use NSUSerdefaults, because I plan to use Core Data iCloud sync later, so I really need it like that: One single Object with one Entity that has some attributes that the user can edit while using the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be basically the same setup as your previous app. When you create the Core Data stack, run a count fetch to see if your object exists, and if it doesn't create it. After that the usage is just the same, it's just that you don't have any code to create a new object anywhere else in the app.

Comment: Thx, I figuered it out meanwhile... everything is a bit messy and probably not the best way to implement but it s working...